# remove first '11' chars of a string from a cell - excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Ive got an excel sheet like with data in **A1** like this `2013-05-24 16:55:04`, i want to be left with just the time, hh:mm:ss part of that string.

Is there a way i can write in cell **B1** somthing like `= cut first 11 chars off A1` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if it is stored as text, then

```
=MID(A1,12,LEN(A1)-11)
```

would work

If it's a date/time value then you have

```
=A1-INT(A1)
```

to return the value as a number, or

```
=TEXT(A1,"hh:mm:ss")
```

to return the value as text

Comment: +1, you can also use MOD function to get the time, i.e. `=MOD(A1,1)`

Answer (score 4):

If the string you have is really a date/time, you might be better off with:

```
=TEXT(A1, "hh:mm:ss")
```

Answer (score 2):

What happens if you replace *_ (asterisk space) with nothing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MID or RIGHT function. MID would be better, I think. The syntax would be something like: `=MID(A1,12,LEN(A1)-11`.

#### How the formula works

MID takes 3 arguments:

- the input string, or a reference to a cell that contains the input string
- the starting character that MID will return
- the number of characters to return.

So, A1 holds the input string, the first character to return is the 12th one (skipping the first 11), and the length of the string to return is just the length of the complete string minus the 11 characters that are being skipped.

Answer (score 0):

This should work

=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-11)

Comment: Thanks, ive given this a shot and its returning `74074` for the data `2013-05-24 16:55:04` any ideas why this would be ?

Comment: Yes. Because A1 is not actually saved as text but a time so the cut doesn't correctly work. Try Sean Cheshire's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the MID function explained [here](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/Text-Functions/ss/2011-01-31-excel-2010-truncate-text-strings-mid-function.htm)

If you can't be bothered to read that, here's the syntax

= MID ( Text , Start_num , Num_chars )